# Passing arguments to code executed via asyncafter

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

so I'm trying to execute multiple lines of code after a delay. Asyncafter in grand central dispatch doesnt seem to provide a way to pass information to the code to be executed.
for example, I'd like to execute func(1) after 0.1 seconds, func(2) after 0.2 seconds, and func(3) after 0.3 seconds
how do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You don’t have to “pass” the information. The closure will automatically “[*capture*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html#ID103) constants and variables from the surrounding context”:

```
for i in 0 ..< 1000 {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(i) / 10) {
        self.func(i)
    }
}
```

---

Maybe you were just using this as an example, it is worth noting that if you want to do something at some regular interval, `asyncAfter` has a few disadvantages:

1. If you might need to cancel this process (e.g. maybe the view in question was dismissed), canceling multiple, individually scheduled, blocks dispatched with `asyncAfter` becomes a bit cumbersome and unwieldy.
2. When you schedule many blocks in the future, `asyncAfter` is subject to “timer coalescing” where dispatched blocks that are scheduled within 10% of each other will start firing at the same time. (This is a power saving feature.)

So, if you want to schedule something to fire at some regular interval, we would use a repeating timer:

```
var i = 0
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.1, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
    guard let self = self, i < 1000 else {
        timer.invalidate()
        return
    }
    
    self.func(i)

    i += 1
}
```

But, again, we do not have to “pass” a variable to the `Timer` closure. We can just use that variable directly from within the closure.

But, if you really were only scheduling three calls, at 0.1, 0.2, and 0.3 seconds, respectively, then `asyncAfter` is fine. But if you were planning on adding a lot of these calls (where cancelation and/or timer coalescing becomes an issue), then consider a `Timer`.